# Update-Database looking for Entity Framework 4.4 but I'm using EF 5

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I am using MySQL with dotConnector from Devart. I'm trying to use the code-first with migrations that the library offers. It creates the migrations just fine, but when I try to call Update-Database in the package manager I'm getting this error

`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

Digging through my reference list, I'm using EntityFramework 5.0.0.0 and am targeting the v4.5 framework. Why would this be asking for v4.4 of EF?

I set up two connection strings, one using the regular MySQL provider, the other using dotConnector's MySQL provider, it didn't make a difference which one my context used. I've tried removing and re-adding the EF reference.

I'm so lost on this I don't even know what other information to give to help get a constructive answer. So, if there is more information I should give to help get a better answer, please let me know.

I've found more information about [dotConnect](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/history.html) and it looks like the Migrations portion targets 4.4. Does this mean I need to use EF 4.4? Or can I have both somehow so the migration has what it needs and I can use EF 5.0 everywhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF 4.4 is .NET 4.0 version of EF 5.0. It looks like something in your project is targeting .NET 4.0 (or is built for .NET 4.0).

Comment: You think the MySQL providers I am using may be targeting .NET 4.0? This may be an entirely new question but what does Update-Database use to run the migrations?

Comment: Update-Database must use the provider to connect to database.

Comment: Is there a way I can use EF 4.4 just to run migrations and 5.0 for the rest?

Comment: in my references i have Entity Framework, when i go in its properties, i see that runtinme version is v4.0.30319 and Version is 4.4.0.0, what this means does it means my solution is using EF 4.4? @LadislavMrnka